# How to avoid webbrowser.open asking to save file?

Tags: python, browser

I'm new to python. Trying to open a webpage in the browser...

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://stockcharts.com/c-sc/sc?s=COP&p=D&b=5&g=1&id=p77498320782', new=2, autoraise=True)
```

Result is disappointing, because the browser asks me to download the file (Open/Save/Cancel) instead of opening it in the browser. I do not want to save the file, I want it to be **instantly** displayed in the browser.

When I copy-paste the URL "http://stockcharts.com/c-sc/sc?s=COP&p=D&b=5&g=1&id=p77498320782" into the browser address bar it displays the page as expected (i.e. it does not ask me to download the file). **How to make python do this?**

As a **workaround** I’m currently retrieving the file to disk, and then using a html template to display it in the browser like this:

```
import os
import webbrowser
from urllib import urlretrieve

urlretrieve('http://stockcharts.com/c-sc/sc?s=COP&p=D&b=5&g=1&id=p77498320782', os.path.join('C:\stock\python', 'image.png'))
webbrowser.open(os.path.join('C:\stock\python', 'image.html'), new=2, autoraise=True)
```

If anyone knows a better solution, please show me…

Comment: Are you trying to launch a browser and open the URL?

Comment: Using chrome as my default browser, it opened and displayed correctly as you described. What is your default browser?

Comment: On my side, this displays "Please visit StockCharts.com" in a GIF image. Maybe a cookie problem?

Comment: Thank you guys, I just tried it on my linux machine (Fedora 20, with Firefox 26.0) and it works fine.

Comment: On my Win 7 machine, default browser is IE 8. So it means that I need to find the right browser settings in order to fix this...
Any clues what setting to change?

Comment: "Are you trying to launch a browser and open the URL? – Ryan O'Donnell"
Yes that is what I expect from this code to do.

Comment: If this so sensitive to browser settings, is there a way to display the contents of a webpage in a figure (for example with matplotlib) ?